# Java Web application which is required to be both web-friendly and mobile friendly

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Currently, My team have a JSF/primefaces web application which is perfectly functioning but the interface is web-friendly only because of the many forms inputs.
We are asked to go for an approach (preferably make use of the current JSF/PF implementation) that's both web-friendly and mobile-friendly.

I tried to convert some pages using PFM (primefaces mobile) but the interface become only mobile-friendly and looks weird when opened from normal desktop browser!

My thoughts are to use two different versions of the same web page (for example index.xhtml & m_index.xhtml) and use a generic listener to direct to the proper page according to the "operating system" used.

I'm asking for help is that approach is the best or there's better one? If it's cool, can you please provide some help how to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you could integrte bootstap in you pages.  I never tried, mighe be an option

Comment: Try googling. This question is really too broad for StackOverflow (generally speaking, if you dont have code to show, here is probably not the right place to be asking).

Comment: I'm asking for providing a general architectural solution for both web & mobile UI responsive optimization, it's not about code.

Answer (score 1):

With using a responsive approach, I was able to create a web application most likely like yours (datagrids and forms) that is both desktop, table and mobile friendly (all are web ;-)). It requires some css tweaks, but I was able to just use a 'shared' page then  between all devices.

Think e.g. of labels that show up above the input instead of next to it. The context menu showing up in the middle of the screen instead of at the 'long push' location and more of these tweaks.

Some components are not fully optimized then for mobile devices (the selectOneMenu looks the same on all devices and is thus a little more heavy than the optimized mobile ones, but it works surprisingly good).

If you realy need different components, you can always use the UAGentInfo mentioned above, but not to render different pages, but to decide to render a default component or a more simple one.

I'm in the process of submitting my basic changes as pull requests to PrimeFaces so everybody can benefit from it, but I'm even thinking of 'merging' some of the normal and mobile components and to have a kind of auto-detection mechanism in them.

So basically, you can have one solution that is just a little less optimized for mobile but still works reasonably well. It just requires some more advanced css usage.

Answer (score -1):

**First of all, I don't recommend you to follow this approach. You should try with some responsive library.**

However, if you are bound to severe restriction of using two view, you can consider following approach:

For the separation of views based on the device detection, you can utilize server-side utility like [UAgentInfo.java](https://gist.github.com/bryanjswift/318237) to identify the request device.

To achieve this, you need to wrap your both views in a container xhtml file, let say `indexContainer.xhtml`, which should look like following: (assuming your bean as `Index.java`)

```
<f:view xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

        <c:if test="#{!Index.isMobileDevice}">
            <ui:include src="/index.xhtml" />
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="#{Index.isMobileDevice}">
            <ui:include src="/m_index.xhtml" />
        </c:if>
</f:view>
```

Include `indexContainer.xhtml` as view where you were previously including `index.xhtml` in configuration file(s).

Wrap mobile devices detector methods in local utility class (`Utility.java`) of x.x.x package to return a boolean incase of match as following:

```
public static boolean isMobileDevice(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){
    boolean isMobileDevice = false;

    String userAgent = httpServletRequest.getHeader("User-Agent");
    String httAccept = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Accept");

    UAgentInfo uAgentInfo = new UAgentInfo(userAgent, httAccept);
    isMobileDevice = uAgentInfo.detectAndroid() || uAgentInfo.detectIphone() || 
                     uAgentInfo.isMobilePhone && uAgentInfo.detectWebkit();

    return isMobileDevice;  
}
```

Add a boolean property with setter & getter in your `Index.java`, say `isMobileDevice` and populate it with above method call in initialization of your bean, as following:

```
setMobileDevice(Utility.isMobileDevice(httpServletRequest));
```

Now, populated `isMobileDevice` will be available on container view, which will filter view based on its truth value.

Comment: @Samir Afifi, Are you looking for something like this?

Answer (score -2):

If you use a CSS-Framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) you can have one html code which is optimize for both.

Bootstrap work with a grid-system which control the flow of div's so its definitly worth to look at.